# Correctly echo out multiple values in an implode array_column

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo out 2 different values from an Array in a single line, so far I've had no luck.

They Array looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 525
            [name] => #02C - Cleaning
            [price] => 24000.00
            [price_gross] => 24000
            [price_type] => 1
            [quantity] => 1
            [tax_rate_value] => 0
            [sum_net] => 24000
            [sum_gross] => 24000
        )

)
```

The current method in the system is like this.

```
<?php echo implode(array_column($post->cpbs_booking_extra, 'name'), '<br />'); ?>
```

Works fine and looks as expected as this:

```
#02C - Cleaning
```

That currently just echos out the name value, I am trying to echo out with the price as well like this

```
Value=NAME - Value=PRICE
```

I have tried multiple ways that I found here in stackoverflow but so far none of them actually worked and they did not echo out anything, not sure if this is some unusual method or what.

Canyone has an idea?.

Comment: If you want "Value=NAME - Value=PRICE" exactly like that then just [map the array and use sprintf()](https://3v4l.org/aftr0) to choose what you want it to say. I don't understand why you are not looping your top level array though... would be much easier to just output what you need...

Comment: What makes you think your task is done by array_column? I see not a single reason for this function. Why don't you just loop over your array?

Comment: What's the problem with just foreach($post->cpbs_booking_extra as $row) {echo $row['name'], '-',$row['price'], '<br />';}